# Adding global attribute using xarray

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

Is there some way to add a global attribute to a `netCDF` file using `xarray`? When I do something like `hndl_nc['global_attribute'] = 25`, it just adds a new variable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Xarray, directly indexing a `Dataset` like `hndl_nc['variable_name']` pulls out a `DataArray` object. To get or set attributes, index `.attrs` like `hndl_nc.attrs['global_attribute']` or `hndl_nc.attrs['global_attribute'] = 25`.

You can access both variables and attributes using Python's attribute syntax like `hndl_nc.variable_or_attribute_name`, but this is a convenience feature that only works when the variable or attribute name does not conflict with a preexisting method or property, and cannot be used for setting.

Answer (score 7):

I would add here that both Datasets and DataArrays can have attributes, both called with `.attrs`
e.g.
`ds.attrs['global attr'] = 25`
`ds.variable_2.attrs['variable attr'] = 10`
`ds.variable_2.attrs['variable attr'] = 10`