# Reading a global attribute in xarray?

Tags: python, linux, python-xarray, netcdf4

I'm trying to read a global attribute within python using xarray from a netcdf4 file. I can see the global attribute in nc_dump from the linux command line.  I've tried:

```
print(ds['global_attribute'])
print(ds.attrs['global_attribute'])
```

Within python, I note that when I use `print(ds.variables.keys())`, the global attributes don't show up.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41794956/adding-global-attribute-using-xarray

Comment: Thanks. That link is where I obtained the commands I tried above. Didn't work for me. Where there other methods or some way I can check the validity of the file? Seeing the global attributes in "ncdump" was my naive way of doing a check.

Comment: It should work if you use `ds.attrs['global_attribute']` rather than `ds.attrs('global_attribute')`. Also, `ds.attrs.keys()` .

Comment: Thanks Robert, you caught my mistake. I was using the wrong parantheses. Dang it! Greatly appreciate your help